# Change owner of files created inside a Docker container without changing the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I create a file inside a container with `docker-compose run web touch test` the file owns to `root:root`. I want to change it to be `$USER` without to use `chown`.

I'm aware of the `--user` option but it requires to have the user created on the `Dockerfile`. I prefer to not change the `Dockerfile` because it is committed on a git repo and I don't want to commit this because it is kind of personal config.

I tried to mount the file `/etc/passwd` but the user is not present when we run a command. I can use `su $USER -c "..."` but there is some issues with this.

So, what's the best way to set create new files with the owner set as the user of the host machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to change the Dockerfile. Just define a certain user, e.g. jenkins and a certain uid, e.g. `1000` and ensure the same uid is used when a folder is mounted.

> ```
> ARG user=jenkins
> ARG uid=1000
>
> # Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000
> # If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data container,
> # ensure you use the same uid
> RUN mkdir -p $JENKINS_HOME \
>     && chown ${uid}:${gid} $JENKINS_HOME \
>     && addgroup -g ${gid} ${group} \
> && adduser -h "$JENKINS_HOME" -u ${uid} -G ${group} -s /bin/bash -D ${user}
>
> RUN chown -R ${user} "$JENKINS_HOME" /usr/share/jenkins/ref
> ```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine

Comment: It makes sense. Do you know if there is a solution without creating a user in the Dockerfile at all?

Comment: It works on debian systems with `RUN addgroup --gid 1000 devgroup && adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos "" --uid 1000 --gid 1000 devuser`

Comment: what if this is a external volume mounted after your container is built